# I am trying to read a .csv file which contains data in the order of timestamp, number plate, vehicle type and exit/entry

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I need to store the timestamps  in a list for further operations and  have written the following code:

```
    import csv
    from datetime import datetime

    from collections import defaultdict
    t = []
    columns = defaultdict(list)
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
    with open('log.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            #t = row[1]
            for i in range(len(row)):
                columns[i].append(row[i])

            if (row):
                t=list(datetime.strptime(row[0],fmt))


    columns = dict(columns)

    print (columns)
    for i in range(len(row)-1):

        print (t)
```

But I am getting the error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parking.py", line 17, in <module>
    t = list(datetime.strptime(row[0],fmt))
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable
```

What can I do to store each timestamp in the column in a list?

Edit 1:
Here is the sample log file

```
2011-06-26 21:27:41.867801,KA03JI908,Bike,Entry
2011-06-26 21:27:42.863209,KA02JK1029,Car,Exit
2011-06-26 21:28:43.165316,KA05K987,Bike,Entry
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a csv file than why not use pandas to get what you want.The code for your problem may be something like this.

```
import Pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('log.csv')
timestamp=df[0]
```

if the first column of csv is of Timestamp than you have an array with having all the entries in the first column in the list known as timestamp.

After this you can convert all the entries of this list into timestamp objects using datetime.datetime.strptime().

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment for clarifications yet. 
Would this code get you the timestamps in a list? If yes, give me a few lines of data from the csv file.

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamps = []
with open(csv_path, 'r') as readf_obj:
    for line in readf_obj:
        timestamps.append(line.split(',')[0])
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
datetimes_timestamps = [datetime.strptime(timestamp_, fmt) for timestamp_ in timestamps]
```

Comment: I am getting the error :                                                               ValueError: time data '\n' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'. I have added the log file for clarity.

Comment: I'm not getting this error with your example data. Can you give any more info? If this is a public repo, post its link.